# Best way to filter statements from a .log?

Tags: java, logging, filter, notepad

I do not have a clue but what would be the best way to make a filter on a server.log file so it pulls any lines starting with severe into a separate notepad document to debug easier.

If it helps its a console log for a java based game and I am just experimenting.

Comment: If its a unix based OS, then `grep` would be a good tool

Comment: Try this http://glogg.bonnefon.org/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154982/what-is-the-best-log-analysis-tool-that-you-used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, where you are printing out the logs, simply substring/contains the exception to check if it is 'severe', if so append that to a file from there. No need to go to your console and filter to the file manually.

```
if(<yourException.toString()>.contains("severe")){
    <code to append exception to file>
}
```

[How to append to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)